# poemscol: How to fix slight indent with \startverseline?

Tags: line-numbering

I'm using `\startverseline` to get my line numbers aligned with the beginning of a runover line (as described in the poemscol manual, 3.3.2). The line number is now in the right place, but the line is slightly indented. Does anyone know of a work-around for this? Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, poemscol}

\setverselinemodulo{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{poem}
\begin{stanza}
Short line\verseline
Long line without startverseline --- long long long long 
long long long long long long long long line\verseline
Short line\verseline
\startverseline Long line with startverseline, numbered --- 
long long long long long long long long long long line\verseline
Short line\verseline
Short line\verseline
\startverseline Long line with startverseline, not numbered --- 
long long long long long long long long long long line\verseline
Short line\end{stanza}
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

I get this problem: the runover lines with `\startverseline` are slightly indented, whether they have a line number or not:

[image]

I'm using up to date versions of xelatex and poemscol:

```
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020)
Package: poemscol 2020/06/12 v3.141592 poemscol file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package adds dozens of % at ends of lines but misses a couple where they are needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, poemscol}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\verseline}{\ifspeciallinelock%
\relax\else%
\nolinebreak\incrementverselinenumber%
\fi%
\speciallinelockfalse%
\nolinebreak\\%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}


\renewcommand{\incrementverselinenumber}{%
\nolinebreak\addtocounter{verselinenumber}{1}%
%%NO! \makeatletter
 \@ifundefined{marksthe}{\relax}{\marksthe{verselinemark}{\theverselinenumber}}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%%NO! \makeatother
  \addtocounter{printlineindex}{1}%
  \ifnum\theprintlineindex>\thelineindexrepeat%
    \ifverselinenumbers\nobreak%
      \putverselinenumber\nobreak%
    \fi\nobreak%
    \setcounter{printlineindex}{0}%
   \fi%
}


\makeatother
\setverselinemodulo{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{poem}
\begin{stanza}
Short line\verseline
Long line without startverseline --- long long long long 
long long long long long long long long line\verseline
Short line\verseline
\startverseline Long line with startverseline, numbered --- 
long long long long long long long long long long line\verseline
Short line\verseline
Short line\verseline
\startverseline Long line with startverseline, not numbered --- 
long long long long long long long long long long line\verseline
Short line\end{stanza}
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That takes care of it.

Comment: Thank you, David Carlisle. That's an embarrassing slip on my part. I've uploaded a corrected version